# Realizar una comparación de archivos de videos con php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando comprar archivos de tipo video como mp4, avi, etc en php.

Puedo comprar archivos de tipo imagen con el siguiente código y no tengo problemas para comparar imagen y mostrarlas, pero con los videos no lo he podido hacer.

¿Podrían ayudarme por favor con este tema? Gracias de antemano por el apoyo que me puedan brindar.

```php
    <?php if($ticket->file2!=""):?>
    <?php
    $filename = "./storage/tickets/".$ticket->file2;
                                                
    $size = getimagesize($filename);
    switch ($size['mime']) {
        case "image/gif":
            //echo "Image is a gif";
               echo " <center>$ticket->file2 <a href=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 target='_new'> <i class='fa fa-file-o'> Ver</i></a></center><h>";
            echo "<center><img src=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 style=border-radius:80px; width='50%' height=60%></center><br>";
            break;
        case "image/jpg":
            //echo "Image is a jpg";
               echo " <center>$ticket->file2 <a href=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 target='_new'> <i class='fa fa-file-o'> Ver</i></a></center><h>";
            echo "<center><img src=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 style=border-radius:80px; width='50%' height=60%></center><br>";
            break;
        case "image/png":
            //echo "Image is a png";
              echo " <center>$ticket->file2 <a href=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 target='_new'> <i class='fa fa-file-o'> Ver</i></a></center><h>";
            echo "<center><img src=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 style=border-radius:80px; width='50%' height=60%></center><br>";
            break;
        case "image/bmp":
            //echo "Image is a bmp";
               echo " <center>$ticket->file2 <a href=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 target='_new'> <i class='fa fa-file-o'> Ver</i></a></center><h>";
            echo "<center><img src=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 style=border-radius:80px; width='50%' height=60%></center><br>";
            break;
            case "image/jpeg":
        //echo " Image is a jpeg";
         echo " <center>$ticket->file2 <a href=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 target='_new'> <i class='fa fa-file-o'> Ver</i></a></center><h>";
            echo "<center><img src=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 style=border-radius:80px; width='50%' height=60%></center><br>";
          
            break;
            
              default:
            //echo "NO ES UN ARCHIVO DE TIPO IMAGEN";
         echo "<center>$ticket->file <a href=./storage/tickets/$ticket->file2 target='_new'> <i class='fa fa-file-o'> Ver</i></a></center><br>";

    }
    ?>

     <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ajaaa, ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask]. Porque has puesto algo que nada tiene que ver con videos, la lógica es la misma.

Answer (score 1):

En efecto como dice OCHOA, la lógica es la misma, lo que debes hacer es extraer el `mime_content_type` de tus archivos, el resto es lo mismo.

```
echo 'Tipo es: '.$file = mime_content_type('video.mp3');

// Tipo es: video/mp4
```

Mira bien que en el ejemplo yo analizo un "mp3" pero en realidad en mi carpeta lo que tengo es un **video.mp4**, lo hice así para comprobar que aunque la extensión del archivo no corresponde al archivo en cuestión, el **mime type** es el que ocuparas para seguir el código que tu ya tienes para analizar las imágenes.